# SQL window function and running total

Tags: sql, window-functions

I'm learning SQL and want to understand the window function better.

Let's say I have a set of data for a bank account containing:

1. Latest balance (It only shows the latest balance and not historical ones)
2. Transaction Date
3. Deposit amount
4. Withdrawal amount

Out of this data, I want to get a column that shows running total ('balance') at everey transaction as below:

<◎What it should look like>

| account | latest_balance | date | deposit | withdrawal | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | 1 000 | 2021-07-16 | 100 |  | 1 000 |
| XYZ | 1 000 | 2021-07-15 |  | 200 | 900 |

Because the data does not contain the entire transaction history of this account and the available date is of the latest 1 year, one way to get 'balance' is to make a calculation based on the latest balance. I have tried using the window function for this. However I haven't been able to make it work the way I want to.

For example, if I write this part of the select statement like below:

```
SELECT
latest_balance
- (ISNULL (SUM(deposit) OVER(PARTITION BY account ORDER BY date DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING),0)
   + ISNULL (SUM(withdrawal)) OVER(PARTITION BY account ORDER BY date DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING),0))
```

This would return something like below:

<✖ How it looks now>

| account | latest_balance | date | deposit | withdrawal | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | 1 000 | 2021-07-16 | 100 |  | 900 |
| XYZ | 1 000 | 2021-07-15 |  | 200 | 700 |

This is not what I would like to see as the balance for the first row should say 1 000 instead of 900. I tried different conbinations of ROWS, BETWEEN, UNBOUNDED, PRECEDING and FOLLOWING for this but I still can't figure out how to make it work.

Could anyone please share your knowledge and enlighten me? Many thanks! =)

Comment: for MySQL see: [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html) and for MSSQL see: [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).  Both explain the basic things you should (or would?) like to know about it.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want `latest_balance` with the cumulative sum of `deposit` and `withdrawal` removed *up to the previous row*.

That would be:

```
select t.*,
       (latest_balance -
        coalesce(sum(deposit) over (partition by account order by date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0) +
        coalesce(sum(withdrawal) over (partition by account order by date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0)
       ) as balance
from t;
```